# ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor initialize resource on thread start and inject it to worker-runnable

Tags: java, multithreading, zeromq, executorservice, jeromq

I have a resource (in my case zmq socket, but this detail can be ignored).
The resource is not thread safe, and can be used only from a thread, that opened connection.

I want to use it in ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.
So my ideal workflow would be:

- thread on startup opens a connection
- every worker task should implement and interface (socketAware)
- socket from current thread gets injected to a worker via the method of the interface.

  ```
  ScheduledExecutorService service = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(5, new SocketAwareThreadFactory(socket));
  service.scheduleAtFixedRate(new SocketAwareRunable(), 0, 5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);


  public class SocketAwareThreadFactory implements ThreadFactory {
      private final Proxyable socket;

      SocketAwareThreadFactory(Proxyable socket) {
          this.socket = socket;
      }

      @Override
      public Thread newThread(@Nonnull Runnable action) {
          return new SocketAwareThread(socket, action);
      }
  }

  public class SocketAwareThread extends Thread {

      private final Socket proxy;

      public SocketAwareThread(Proxyable socket, Runnable action) {
          super(action);
          proxy = socket.proxy();
      }

      @Override
      public void run() {
          proxy.open();//connection opens here
          super.run();
      }
  }
  ```

Is there any way now to propagate opened socket back to every Runable that is executed by this thread, except of using reflection ?

It looks like ThreadPoolExecutor.beforeExecute could do the trick, but it does not work with ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor, since runnable is not what I have submitted, but something already decorated.

Comment: You can just use a common (static?) variable with access to it synchronized so it is only initialized once.

Comment: have you considered using a ThreadLocal shared between your custom thread implementation and your task target type?  Your `SocketAwareRunable` would get the Socket of the ThreadLocal.